# Why is `viewDidAppear` method called again on previous root view controller when swapping root view controller on window?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

In a project a root view controller is being swapped at some point to recreate a whole window hierarchy. A pretty standard code is called simply using

```
windows.rootViewController = newController
```

but this code instantly calls `viewDidAppear` on the view controller that is about to be destroyed. And it is only called on root view controller. The method `viewDidAppear` is correctly called after a while on `newController` but why would it be called on the previous view controller?

To extract the issue I created a new project and added minimum amount of code that produces the issue. So if you create a new project and just modify your autogenerated `ViewController.swift` to following you should be able to produce the issue:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    static var loadInstance: Int = 0
    var instance: Int = -1
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        ViewController.loadInstance += 1
        self.instance = ViewController.loadInstance
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("Calling did appear on instance: \(instance)")
        
        let controller = AnotherController()
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        controller.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

class AnotherController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap)))
    }
    
    @objc private func onTap() {
        print("Swapping root")
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()!
    }
}
```

The root view controller needs to have presented at least one other view controller for the issue to work. It needs to be as full screen as well.

In this example as you press your screen a new controller will be created which swaps the root and presents a new red view controller. Each time you do so you can see the log that the previous root controller reports `viewDidAppear` being called. The log looks like the following:

```
Calling did appear on instance: 1
Swapping root
Calling did appear on instance: 1
Calling did appear on instance: 2
Swapping root
Calling did appear on instance: 2
Calling did appear on instance: 3
```

Simply removing full screen setting produces expected result:

```
Calling did appear on instance: 1
Swapping root
Calling did appear on instance: 2
Swapping root
Calling did appear on instance: 3
```

Is there a reason for this or is it just a bug? In any case: Is there a solution to go around it and still safely use `viewDidAppear` for root controller?

Note that this is just a minimal presentation of the issue. The actual application is a bit more complex.

Comment: @matt the standard code was related to swapping the root view controller. But never mind that. Would you be kind enough to also point just a single one much-better-way to make it possible to tear down and replace the whole interface please.

Comment: @Matic Oblak, just add print in either `viewWillDisappear` or `viewDidDisappear` to both ViewController and AnotherController, you'll see why this is happening.

If I am not mistaken, because you use modal presentation to show AnotherController, when removing ViewController, it needs to hide AnotherController first, by doing that, it shows ViewController (hence viewWillAppear is called).

Comment: @matt Adding a child means that all presented view controllers need to be dismissed as well. Which means that all controllers will receive "appear" signals and all logic will be executed. This solution appears to be much worse actually. Or maybe you will need to add some more information.

Comment: @Bill well the controller should not be shown and does not appear to be shown at all. Just the method is being called. Note that presenting more controllers does not change the logic; only the root controller notifies that it appears. By your logic I would assume that all controller need to "hide first" which means all presenting controllers would notify they are being appeared.

Comment: how about just add viewWillAppear to ViewController. Before you tap, set a break point, you should be able to see `-[UIWindow setRootViewController:]`, click on that, you should be able to see `_removeAllViewControllersFromWindowHierarchyFromDealloc:"`.

In order for UIWindow to remove current rootViewController, it needs to do clean up, which will remove any views using model presentation first. However, in doing that, it will result in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear to be called for  the view underneath it.

Comment: BTW, if this behavior is not what you want, maybe you can take a look at [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller)? `UINavigationController` handle's its own view stack. If you use it as a rootViewController, when replacing another one, when it cleans up, the stack is removed together, so you won't get the behavior you are getting using model present.